# Task Groups Asking for Output Variables That Should Be Created By The Task Automatically

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

From what I understand, an output variable is created by a task automatically. So why does a Task Group pick them up? And how to I avoid manually putting values for it?

Here are

[image: Output Variables]

automatically added by the task. When I create the the Task Group

[image: it asks me to provide them].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Task Groups Asking for Output Variables That Should Be Created By The Task Automatically

I am afraid we could not use the Output Variables in the Task Group.

AFAIK, the output variables aren't currently supported within task groups. we would recommend currently not using isOutput=true within tasks groups.

You could check [this thread](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/output-variables-defined-in-task-group-are-not-wor/245845) and [this thread](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/task-groups-parameters-are-not-populated-by-variab/507586) for some more details.